# How to get the action of displayModeButtonItem in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an `UISplitViewController`.

In it the master is an `UITableViewController` and the details in an `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView` in it

I added the `displayModeButtonItem` to the details `ViewController`.

When i press in the `detailsViewController` turn to full screen
but the `collectionView` stays in the width of the small.
When `reloadData()` is called everything goes back to normal and looks great.

So my question is:

How  can i get/override the action of tapping on the `displayModeButtonItem` that i will be able to call reload data?

Or how can i make it work correctly that the `collectionView` will be the right size?

---

**Comment**

If i switch the details `ViewController` to a `UITableViewController` everything works great straight out of the box.

Thanks.